# strange global variable behavior on import

Tags: python, global-variables

Yes: I know that we shouldn't be using global variables in Python but I'm trying to understand this behavior.

I have this file called bug.py   :

```
x = 0


def foo():
    global x
    x = 100


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    print(x)
```

when I execute this as a file I get the expected result of a 100, see below.

```
(mani) franz@ubuntu:~/dropboxpython/poolparty$ python bug.py
100
```

However, when I do the same thing in the repl, x doesn't turn 100, see below

```
(mani) franz@ubuntu:~/dropboxpython/poolparty$ python
Python 3.6.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 23 2017, 16:31:06) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bug import *
>>> x
0
>>> foo()
>>> x
0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: After executing `foo()` if we executes `from bug import *` again then value of x changes to 100 and prints 100 every time.

Comment: That's weird especially since the above assignment of x = 0 in bug.py is superfluous. Calling foo() will set x to a global and assign 100 to it.

Comment: I think this changes x within the bug module, but not within your currently imported x. If you did import bug, then bug.foo(), I think bug.x would be 100.

Comment: Do not use wildcard imports

Answer (score 3):

Let's recap what is the `from module import something` statement doing:

> a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the
>   name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise using the attribute
>   name

I'd like to add also that `module` is imported (i.e. added to `sys.modules`), but the name `module` is not created.

The second important point is that integers are immutable. Immutable objects behave like this, because each value is a separate object:

```
a = 0 # a-->0
b = a # a-->0<--b
a = 3 # 3<--a 0<--b; new object int(3) is created; b is still 0
```

So what is happeing is the import creates a local `x` initialized to `x` from `bug` which is zero. Calling `foo()` changes `x` in the `bug` module, but as shown above, it cannot affect the local `x`.

---

Try this to see the difference between immutable `x` and mutable `y`:

```
x = 0
y = [0]

def foo():
    global x, y
    x = 100
    y[0] = 100

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

```
>>> from bug import *
>>> x, y
(0, [0])
>>> foo()
>>> x, y
(0, [100])
>>>
```

UPDATE: checking the `x` set by `foo`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['bug'].x
100
```

Answer (score 1):

*Globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules.* If you want to use `x` from the module bug then use it by importing `bug` module like below.

```
>>> import bug
>>> bug.x
0
>>> bug.foo()
>>> bug.x
100
>>>
```

Don't use a `from bug import *`. This will create a new variable `x` initialized to whatever `bug.x` referred to at the time of the import. If you assign x=50 in bug.py file then you will get 50 after executing statement `from bug import *` like below.

```
>>> from bug import *
>>> x
50
>>>
```

This new variable `x` would not be affected by assignments from the method `foo()`. This is the reason second time it won't gives you value 100 of variable x.

I tried to simplify it. Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks: I get it now! Being a lisper getting into python will confuse one now and then.